# Multiple redirects from IP to URL and http to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to do the following redirections on an apache webserver (IBM HTTP Server), however when I try to achieve it, one seems to break the other

- http://123.123.123.123 -> http**s**://test.example.com/circle
- http://123.123.123.123/circle -> http**s**://test.example.com/circle
- http://123.123.123.123/square-> http**s**://test.example.com/square
- http://test.example.com/circle-> http**s**://test.example.com/circle
- http://test.example.com-> http**s**://test.example.com/circle

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://test.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```